# Accidentally deleted folder with AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I accidentally deleted a folder in visual studio 2010 (with AnkhSVN).

How do I go about 'undeleting' this folder?

I tried copying the folder contents from another machine and it marks them as 'Deleted and New'?

Doing an 'Update to latest version' does nothing.

I also have TortoiseSVN installed but am not having much luck with that either.

I havent 'commited' these deletions, so its just my machine that has the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://www.protocolostomy.com/2007/10/25/recovering-deleted-files-from-an-svn-repository/) on how to recover deleted file.

Answer (score 4):

To revert deletions in AnkhSVN simply go to the pending changes window right the deleted files and folders and choose revert.

To delete what was committed is also quite easy to do in ankhSVN but scary the first time you do it. Before doing this I would update and commit all other changes but don't beleive you have to.

- Right click on the folder that contains the deleted files or folders in visual studio and do "view history"
- Find the revision where these files were deleted
- Right click on the revision and select "revert changes from this revision"
- All the deleted files (and other changes committed in this revision) will now be in your working copy
- Go to the pending changes window and revert any changes you didn't want

Comment: This sounds like just the answer I need, except... I'd never seen this "pending changes window" and didn't know where to find it. Did track it down, in Visual Studio's View menu. Brilliant.